# How do I just calculate the average for a specific set of rows in Rstudio

Tags: r

```
DF <- data.frame(Height = rnorm(100, 170, 5),
                 Weight = rnorm(100, 55, 5))
BMI = function(height,weight){(weight/(height)^2*10000)}
DF$bmi = BMI(DF$Height,DF$Weight)

DF$weight_group <- 
  cut(
    x = DF$Weight,
    breaks = c(0,60,70,Inf),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = c("0-60", "61-70", "71+")
  )

DF$BMI_group <-
  cut(
    x = DF$bmi,
    breaks = c(0, 19.75582, Inf),
    include.lowest = TRUE,
    labels = c("Below Average", "Above Average")
  )
```

This is my code. I cannot figure out how to just calculate the average of the last half of the data frame. I didn't know how to add in gender, to make 50 males and 50 females, so this is my work around.

Comment: sorry, that's a left over. I'll edit it now. Should be DF

Comment: What is the logic for adding `gender`>  Should it be for each wegith_group or BMI_group, 50/50

Comment: Well the 100 participants are split 50/50 into male and females. I am supposed to calculate the average for just the female group... since I do not know how to assign gender to each of the 100 participants I have just arbitrarily said that the last 50 will be female, since this is a random data set anyways.

Comment: You can use `set.seed` to provide a reproducible set of data and then show expected output for it so that we can verify our answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
DF <- data.frame(Height = rnorm(100, 170, 5),
                 Weight = rnorm(100, 55, 5),
                 Gender = c(rep("male", 50), rep("female", 50)))


BMI <-  function(height,weight){(weight/(height)^2*10000)}

library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  mutate(bmi = BMI(Height, Weight)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_bmi = mean(bmi))
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Gender mean_bmi
* <chr>     <dbl>
1 female     19.4
2 male       19.6
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `sample` to create the column, `subset` the 'Gender' for 'F', and apply the `BMI`

```
 DF$Gender <- sample(c("F", "M"), nrow(DF), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
 with(subset(DF, Gender == "F"), mean(BMI(Height, Weight)))
```

---

If we want to get the `mean` of 'BMI' by 'BMI_group'

```
subdf <- subset(DF, Gender == "F")
with(subdf, tapply(BMI(Height, Weight), BMI_group, FUN = mean))
Below Average Above Average 
     17.57841      21.43003
```

Comment: OK, now I am trying to use mean(DF$BMI_group, "F") to get the mean of the women by their BMI group. However it is returning an error: NA. I think this is because BMI_group is a category.

Comment: @Alfred the `BMI_group` is not numeric.  `mean` works on numeric columns

Comment: @Alfred you can check the update